# Regex is including slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm filtering out elements from an array with this regex expression:

```regex
/([A-Za-z'])/g)
```

I have string of words and this is how I'm making an array of it:

```js
const arraylist = text.split(' ').filter(el => el.match(/([A-Za-z'])/g))
```

For some reasons when text is `//wont won't won't` my outcome is `[ '//wont', 'won\'t', 'won\'t' ]`

What am I missing? I want the double slash to be filtered out in my end array

Comment: right now your regex accept any word *included* `A-Za-z'` look like what you looking for is to require *only* this. for that use `/^([A-Za-z'])+$/`

Comment: @PoulBak you should add `+`, for ow your regex accept only one letter, without optional repeating..

Comment: Yosef and Poul, those regex selectors will indeed exclude that word, but does that mean that I need to filter out the // myself? Because I still want the word, just not with the // in front of it

Comment: Don't use text.split and filter, simply use text.match(/\b[A-Za-z']+\b/g) then you will get an array of matches.

Comment: If what you need is to remove the non alphabet letters, instead `.match` use `.replace(/[^A-Za-z']/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understood from your comments on the question - what you actually looking for is **NOT** to filter the word, just remove the non-word letters. For this you can do:

```js
const text = "//wont won't won't";
const arraylist = text.split(' ').map(el => el.replace(/([^A-Za-z'])/g, ''))
console.log(arraylist)
```

Hopefully it s what you looking for